# Problem with the longtable width

Tags: longtable

How can I set the longtable width to be like the textwidth?.

```
\begin{center}

\begin{longtable}{@{}cccccccc@{}}
    \caption[Feasible triples for a highly variable Grid]{Materiales y medios de transporte.} \label{grid_mlmmh} \\

    \hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Semana}}  &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fecha}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Desde}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Hasta}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Acción}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Vol[$ m^{3} $]}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Residuo}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Nro.T}} \\ 
    \hline 
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continuación de la página anterior}} \\
    \hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Semana}}  &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Fecha}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Desde}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Hasta}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Acción}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Vol[$ m^{3} $]}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Residuo}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Nro.T}} \\ 
    \hline
    \endhead

    \hline \multicolumn{7}{r}{{Continúa en la siguiente página}} \\ \hline
    \endfoot

    \hline \hline
    \endlastfoot

    1 & 13-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 13-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 13-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 13-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    1 & 14-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    1 & 14-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.05 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    1 & 14-May & CUNA-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 4 \\ \midrule
    1 & 14-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.3 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    1 & 14-May & CUNA-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 4 \\ \midrule
    1 & 14-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.3 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    1 & 14-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    1 & 14-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    1 & 14-May & GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.2 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    1 & 14-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    1 & 14-May & BOMBA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 15-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    1 & 15-May & CUNA-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    1 & 15-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    1 & 15-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.6 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 15-May & CUNA-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    1 & 15-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.225 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 15-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    1 & 15-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.3375 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 15-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 15-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 15-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 15-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 16-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 16-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 16-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    1 & 16-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    1 & 16-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    1 & 16-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    1 & 16-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    2 & 18-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    2 & 18-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    2 & 18-May & GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO &  & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    2 & 19-May & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.01 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    2 & 19-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    2 & 19-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    2 & 20-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    2 & 20-May & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.01 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    2 & 20-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    2 & 20-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 5.175 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    2 & 20-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.4 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    2 & 20-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 3.375 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    2 & 22-May & BOMBA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    2 & 22-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    2 & 22-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    2 & 22-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    2 & 22-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    2 & 22-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    2 & 22-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    2 & 23-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    2 & 23-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    2 & 23-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    2 & 23-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    2 & 23-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 25-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.3375 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    3 & 25-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    3 & 25-May & CARGA MANUAL & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 8.55 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    3 & 25-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 25-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 25-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 25-May & CARGA MANUAL & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 2.025 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 25-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 26-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    3 & 26-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 26-May & BOMBA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    3 & 26-May & PALA- PICOTA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    3 & 26-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    3 & 26-May & PALA- PICOTA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    3 & 26-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.27 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    3 & 26-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 16.875 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.5 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.35 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.5 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.675 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.15 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 27-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    3 & 28-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 21.375 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    3 & 28-May & CUNA-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 28-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.275 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 28-May & CUNA-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 28-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 28-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 28-May & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 6.3 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
    3 & 28-May & CARGA MANUAL & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.15 & OTRO & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 28-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 3 \\ \midrule
    3 & 29-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 29-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 29-May & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.01 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    3 & 29-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    3 & 29-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    3 & 29-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    3 & 29-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 01-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 01-Jun & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 8.1 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 01-Jun & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 01-Jun & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.875 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 01-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 01-Jun & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 01-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 0.375 & HORMIGON & 3 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & BOMBA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & PALA- PICOTA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.025 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & PALA- PICOTA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 03-Jun & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 3.075 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 03-Jun & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.05 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 03-Jun & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 03-Jun & PALA- PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 4.5 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 03-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 03-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 03-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 04-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 04-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 04-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    4 & 04-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 04-Jun & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.03 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 04-Jun & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.03 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 04-Jun & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.03 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 04-Jun & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.03 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    4 & 04-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    6 & 18-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    6 & 18-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    6 & 18-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    6 & 18-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    6 & 18-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
    7 & 26-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    7 & 26-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
    8 & 30-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{center}
```

Comment: This is documented in the longtable manual `texdoc longtable` page 7, also do not use `\begin{center}` with `longtable` (it doesn't cenmtre it, just adds spurious space)

Answer (score 1):

Is that OK?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{eqparbox} \usepackage{array, longtable, makecell, booktabs}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}

\begin{document}

{\small\setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt}%
  \begin{longtable}{@{\,}*{2}{c}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\eqboxwidth{CG}}%
      >{\arraybackslash}m{\eqboxwidth{CR}}*{4}{c}@{\,}}
      \caption[Feasible triples for a highly variable Grid]{Materiales y medios de transporte.} \label{grid_mlmmh} \\
      \toprule
      \thead{Semana} &
      \thead{Fecha} &
      \thead{Desde} &
      \thead{Hasta} &
      \thead{Acción} &
      \thead{Vol [m\textsuperscript{3}]} &
      \thead{Residuo} & \thead{Nro.T} \\
      \midrule
      \endfirsthead
      %
      \multicolumn{8}{c}%
      {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continuación de la página anterior}} \\
      \addlinespace
      \toprule
      \thead{Semana} &
      \thead{Fecha} &
      \thead{Desde} &
      \thead{Hasta} &
      \thead{Acción} &
      \thead{Vol [m\textsuperscript{3}]} &
      \thead{Residuo} & \thead{Nro.T} \\
      \midrule
      \endhead
      %
      \addlinespace
      \multicolumn{8}{r}{{Continúa en la siguiente página}} \\
      \midrule
      \endfoot
      %
      \bottomrule
      \endlastfoot
      %
      1 & 13-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 13-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 13-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 13-May & \eqmakebox[CG]{CAPACHO-GRUA} & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      1 & 14-May & GRUA & CAMION \eqmakebox[CR]{RESIDUOS} & RETIRO & 1 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      1 & 14-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.05 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      1 & 14-May & CUNA-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 4 \\ \midrule
      1 & 14-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.3 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      1 & 14-May & CUNA-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 4 \\ \midrule
      1 & 14-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.3 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      1 & 14-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      1 & 14-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      1 & 14-May & GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.2 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      1 & 14-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      1 & 14-May & BOMBA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 15-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      1 & 15-May & CUNA-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      1 & 15-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      1 & 15-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.6 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 15-May & CUNA-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      1 & 15-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.225 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 15-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      1 & 15-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.3375 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 15-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 15-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 15-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 15-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 16-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 16-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 16-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      1 & 16-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      1 & 16-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      1 & 16-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      1 & 16-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      2 & 18-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      2 & 18-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      2 & 18-May & GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      2 & 19-May & \eqmakebox[CG]{CARGA MANUAL} & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.01 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      2 & 19-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      2 & 19-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      2 & 20-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      2 & 20-May & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.01 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      2 & 20-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      2 & 20-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 5.175 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      2 & 20-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.4 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      2 & 20-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 3.375 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      2 & 22-May & BOMBA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      2 & 22-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      2 & 22-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      2 & 22-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      2 & 22-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      2 & 22-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      2 & 22-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      2 & 23-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      2 & 23-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      2 & 23-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      2 & 23-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      2 & 23-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 25-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.3375 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      3 & 25-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      3 & 25-May & CARGA MANUAL & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 8.55 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      3 & 25-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 25-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 25-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 25-May & CARGA MANUAL & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 2.025 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 25-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 26-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      3 & 26-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 26-May & BOMBA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      3 & 26-May & PALA-PICOTA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      3 & 26-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      3 & 26-May & PALA-PICOTA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      3 & 26-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.27 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      3 & 26-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 16.875 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.5 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.35 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.5 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.675 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.15 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 27-May & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      3 & 28-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 21.375 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      3 & 28-May & CUNA-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 28-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.275 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 28-May & CUNA-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 28-May & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 28-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 28-May & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 6.3 & MEZCLA & 3 \\ \midrule
      3 & 28-May & CARGA MANUAL & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.15 & OTRO & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 28-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 3 \\ \midrule
      3 & 29-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 29-May & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 29-May & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.01 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      3 & 29-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      3 & 29-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      3 & 29-May & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      3 & 29-May & MIXER & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 01-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 01-Jun & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 8.1 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 01-Jun & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 01-Jun & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.875 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 01-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 01-Jun & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 0 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 01-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & RETIRO.D & 0.375 & HORMIGON & 3 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & BOMBA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.5 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & PALA-PICOTA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.025 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & PALA-PICOTA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 02-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 03-Jun & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 3.075 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 03-Jun & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1.05 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 03-Jun & GRUA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 1 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 03-Jun & PALA-PICOTA & CAMION RESIDUOS & RETIRO & 4.5 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 03-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 03-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & HORMIGON & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 03-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.75 & HORMIGON & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 04-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 04-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 04-Jun & CAPACHO-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      4 & 04-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 04-Jun & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.03 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 04-Jun & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.03 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 04-Jun & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.03 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 04-Jun & CARGA MANUAL & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.03 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      4 & 04-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      6 & 18-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      6 & 18-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      6 & 18-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      6 & 18-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      6 & 18-Jun & CARRETILLA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 0.09 & MEZCLA & 1 \\ \midrule
      7 & 26-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      7 & 26-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & 2 \\ \midrule
      8 & 30-Jun & CUNA-GRUA & ZONA RESIDUOS & ACOPIO & 1.75 & MEZCLA & \\ \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: how can this be modified for `book` class with `twoside` option. the odd page seems to work well, but on the even page the table runs into right margin